# Python pandas split array into cloumn(s)

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to split a csv data containing data with arrays into multiple columns. This works perfectly for most arrays since these are whole numbers, but if I try to split following array (containing dot values) I get a problem.

So here the example. Suppose you have the following array data saved in a column called "Array"

````py
{58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5}

If I apply the following
```python
splitted_data=raw_data["Array"].str.split("\D",expand=True).add_prefix("setrwds_x")
````

I get the follwing result

```
   setrwds_x1  setrwds_x2  setrwds_x4  setrwds_x5  setrwds_x7  setrwds_x8  \
0             58           5          58           5          58           5   
1             58           5          58           5          58           5   
2             58           5          58           5          58           5   
3             58           5          58           5          58           5   
4             58           5          58           5          58           5   
5             58           5          58           5          58           5   
6             58           5          58           5          58           5   
7             58           5          58           5          58           5   
8             58           5          58           5          58           5   
9             58           5          58           5          58           5   
10            58           5          58           5          58           5   
11            58           5          58           5          58           5   
12            58           5          58           5          58           5   
13            58           5          58           5          58           5   
14            58           5          58           5          58           5   
15            58           5          58           5          58           5   
16            58           5          58           5          58           5   
17            58           5          58           5          58           5
```

It splits the 58.5 into two columns, which is wrong. I need to keep the 58.5.

Do you guys have an advice how to solve the problem?

Comment: why aren't you splitting by the `|` delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `\D` in regex stands for non-digit, which includes `|` and `.`, you would want to explicitly split on `|` only. You also need to avoid the first and last bracket using `str[1:-1]`

```
raw_data["Array"].str[1:-1].str.split("|",expand=True).add_prefix("setrwds_x")
```

---

Tested this out with a dummy series -

```
#Dummy series
d = ['{58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5}', 
     '{58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5}', 
     '{58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5 |58.5}']
dd = pd.Series(d)

out = dd.str[1:-1].str.split("|",expand=True).add_prefix("setrwds_x")
print(out)
```

```
  setrwds_x0 setrwds_x1 setrwds_x2 setrwds_x3 setrwds_x4 setrwds_x5  \
0      58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5    
1      58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5    
2      58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5    

  setrwds_x6 setrwds_x7 setrwds_x8 setrwds_x9 setrwds_x10 setrwds_x11  
0      58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5        58.5         58.5  
1      58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5        58.5         58.5  
2      58.5       58.5       58.5       58.5        58.5         58.5
```

Comment: I already tried it before. The problem is that the whole array is saved as string
I get the following output applying your line of code
('Unable to parse string "{58 " at position 0', 'occurred at index realwds_x0')

Comment: Your data seems to have some typos in that case. It seems there is either a `.` or a `|` missing from where it should be

Comment: I editted the array. There is a whitespace before the "|" sign. Hope it gets clearer

Comment: try now.. just added a white space as well.

Comment: I still get the same answer I quoted above, 'Unable to parse string "|58.5" at position 0', 'occurred at index setrwds_x2'

I reallly get mad

Comment: Can you paste 5 rows from the `raw_data["Array"]` as a `pd.Series()`? Put them into your question, so i can operate on it

Comment: Check this solution as well. I have updated my answer

Comment: thank you soo much. Works perfectly :)
I owe you one

Comment: Glad to help. feel free to connect with me incase of future questions on SO. details on my profile. Cheers.